# Difference between {print} & {print;}

Tags: awk

I was going through awk examples and came across something like:

```
awk '{print;}' employee.txt
```

I tried executing the same using `awk '{print}' employee.txt` which gave the same output as previous one.

So can anyone tell what is the significance of using `;` after `print`?

Comment: `;` before closing `}` is optional.

Comment: @anubhava I have been told, multiple times, that it is not optional on BSD systems.  (I don't have BSD access so I can't verify this one way or the other.)

Comment: @John1024, it's not true. Tested on NetBSD, FreeBSD and also on (non-BSD) AIX. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) very clearly says `{print}` is valid, so it might have been true historically, but not for many years. The [FreeBSD man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) clearly says "Statements are terminated by semicolons, newlines or right braces."

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks.  From now on, I'll drop them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely that is a very useful information that I wish you converted into an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put more than one statements inside the `{}` block then semicolon is must to separate those. If you have single stmt  then you don't need to use semicolon. Like anubhava said, you don't need to put `;` for the last stmt if more than one stmts present.

**Example:**

```
$ echo '1 2 3' | awk '{print $1;print $0}'
1
1 2 3
```

Note that each print stmt will print the results in separate lines.

Comment: Multiple statements as in? can you give an example?